# Store data locally on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

From this tutorial https://daattali.com/shiny/persistent-data-storage/, I learnt that it is not possible to store data locally on shinyapps.io

> Since the responses are saved locally, this can only be used if you have access to the machine hosting the app and if you trust its filesystem. If you don't know what machine the app is hosted on, or if the files could get deleted, do not use this method. This approach will not work if hosting on shinyapps.io because of those reasons.

Is this also the case for the premium accounts? I did notice, that you can actually store data locally during the session, but cannot access it after the session close. I assume it's deleted then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the same for premium accounts, and by design. The machine hosting your app can change from one session to the next, and in such case your data will be missing.

Comment: Ok thats a bit unfortunate. Would have been nice and easy to save stuff locally, but I can hopefully manage with the other options provided in the tutorial.